# Read CSV data from GCS bucket and then insert into a GBQ table got wrong position

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, csvhelper, google-cloud-storage

I am working on a project which need to read the data from the GCS bucket using C# CsvHelper, then create a GBQ table and insert data into this GBQ table. However, the data got saved into GBQ is positioned in wrong places.

First, reading the data from GBQ:

```cs
public async Task<MemoryStream> ReadCsvRecord(string url)

{
    Uri gcsUri = new Uri(url);
    // first segment is the '/' and second is the bucket name. Therefore the path should always begin with the third segment
    var path = String.Join("", gcsUri.Segments, 1, gcsUri.Segments.Length - 1);

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    await _storageClient.DownloadObjectAsync(_bucketName, path, stream);
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

Second, create the gbq table and insert the data:

```cs
MemoryStream gcsPayloadStream = await gcsReader.ReadCsvRecord(plannedTripUrl);

var reader = new StreamReader(gcsPayloadStream, Encoding.UTF8, true);
var projectId = this.gbqOpsClient.ProjectId; 
using (reader)
{
    using (CsvReader csvr = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
    {
        csvr.Read();
        csvr.ReadHeader();
        var bigQueryTableInsertRows = new BigQueryTableInsertRows(tableId, projectId);
        string[] headerRowItems = csvr.Context.Reader.HeaderRecord;
        var i = 0;
        while (csvr.Read())
        {
            var key = "";
            var value = "";
            var j = 0;
            ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();
            while (j < headerRowItems.Length)
            {
                key = headerRowItems[j];
                value = csvr.GetField<string>(headerRowItems[j]);
                rows.Add(
                    new BigQueryInsertRow($"{i}{j}")
                    {
                        {key, value}
                    }
                );
                j++;
            }

            var rowArr = rows.ToArray(typeof(BigQueryInsertRow)) as BigQueryInsertRow[];
            bigQueryTableInsertRows.TableInsertRows(rowArr);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The BigQueryTableInsertRows refers Google official documents:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-insert-rows

```cs
public class BigQueryTableInsertRows

    {
        private readonly string tableId;
        private readonly string projectId;
        private readonly string datasetId;

        public BigQueryTableInsertRows(
            string tableId, 
            string projectId,
            string datasetId = "my_datasetId")
        {
            this.tableId = tableId;
            this.projectId = projectId;
            this.datasetId = datasetId;
        }
        
        public void TableInsertRows(BigQueryInsertRow[] rows)
        {
            BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
       
            client.InsertRows(this.datasetId, this.tableId, rows);
        }
        
    }
}
```

However, the final result I got in the GBQ table is like this and only partial data get saved:

```
C1  C2  C3  C4
1A          
    2B      
        3C  
            4D
```

The 1A 2B 3C 4D should be in the same row, but now they are positioned in different rows. Anyone knows what's wrong with my code? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used a GBQ table, but it looks like you are creating a new row for every column value instead of just at the beginning of the reading of the CSV row.  Does something like this work?

```cs
using (CsvReader csvr = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
{
    csvr.Read();
    csvr.ReadHeader();
    var bigQueryTableInsertRows = new BigQueryTableInsertRows(tableId, projectId);
    string[] headerRowItems = csvr.Context.Reader.HeaderRecord;
    var i = 0;
    ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();
    while (csvr.Read())
    {
        var key = "";
        var value = "";
        var j = 0;
        
        var bigQueryRow = new BigQueryInsertRow($"{i}")
        while (j < headerRowItems.Length)
        {
            key = headerRowItems[j];
            value = csvr.GetField<string>(headerRowItems[j]);
            bigQueryRow.Add(key, value);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        rows.Add(bigQueryRow);
    }
    var rowArr = rows.ToArray(typeof(BigQueryInsertRow)) as BigQueryInsertRow[];
    bigQueryTableInsertRows.TableInsertRows(rowArr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly fine. Looks like I put the  ArrayList rows = new ArrayList(); and var bigQueryRow = new BigQueryInsertRow($"{i}") in wrong positions